# How can I add or remove the element in the sub-lists, whose length are different?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

If there are lists with different lengths of sublists like below,

```
list1 = {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {11, 12, 13, 14}, {22, 23, 24, 25}}, {{-1, -2, -3, -4}, {-11,-12,-13, -14}, {-22, -23, -24, -25}, {-41, -42, -43,-44}}, {{100, 200, 300, 400}, {-100, -200, -300, -400}}}
```

How can I combine or delite each element from sublists?Question 1.
I have another data of

```
list2 = {a1, a2, a3},
```

correspond to list1.So I want to combine list2 to each sub element of 
list1;

```
newlist = {{{1, 2, 3, 4, a1}, {11, 12, 13, 14, a1}, {22, 23, 24, 25, a1}}, {{-1, -2, -3, -4, a2}, {-11, -12, -13, -14, a2}, {-22, -23, -24, -25, a2}, {-41, -42, -43, -44, a2}},{{100, 200, 300, 400, a3}, {-100, -200, -300, -400, a3}}}
```

How can I get newlist?
I know I can append a1 to lsmall,

```
lsmall = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {11, 12, 13, 14}, {22, 23, 24, 25}}
```

by

```
Append[lsmall[[#]], {a1}] & /@ Range[Length[lsmall]]
```

However newlist cannot get by

```
Append[lsmall[[#1, #2]], {list2[[#1]]}] & /@ [Range[Length[lsmall]], [Range[Length[lsmall[[#1]]]]]
```

... I' m in trouble.

Question2 After I get

```
newlist = {{{1, 2, 3, 4, a1}, {11, 12, 13, 14, a1}, {22, 23, 24, 25, a1}}, {{-1, -2, -3,-4, a2}, {-11, -12, -13, -14, a2}, {-22, -23, -24, -25, a2}, {-41, -42, -43, -44, a2}},{{100, 200, 300, 400, a3}, {-100, -200, -300, -400, a3}}}
```

in Question 1,
I also want to extract 2 dimensional sub lists,
such as

```
ext1 = {{{1, a1}, {11, a1}, {22, a1}}, {{-1, a2}, {-11, a2}, {-22, a2}, {-41, a2}},{{100, a3}, {-100, a3}}}
```

... (combination of 1 st and last element) or

```
ext2 ={{{2, 3}, {12, 13}, {23, 24}}, {{-2, -3}, {-12, -13}, {-23, -24}, {-42, -43}},{{200, 300}, {-200, -300}}}
```

... (combination of 2 nd and 3 rd element)

I thought

```
For[i = 1, i <= Length[newlist], i++, 
  For[j = 1, j <= Length[newlist[[i]]], j++, 
   ext1 = Transpose[{newlist[[i]][[j]][[All, 1]], 
       newlist[[i]][[j]][[All, 1]]}];]] Return[ext1]
```

But it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way. First I add a zero to the end of each subarray, then I can use `Part` (`[[ ]]`) to easily address and update those elements:

```
list1 = Map[Append[0], list1, {2}];
list1[[All, All, -1]] = list2;
list1
```

> {{{1, 2, 3, 4, a1}, {11, 12, 13, 14, a1}, {22, 23, 24, 25,     a1}},
> {{-1, -2, -3, -4, a2}, {-11, -12, -13, -14,     a2}, {-22, -23, -24,
> -25, a2}, {-41, -42, -43, -44, a2}}, {{100,     200, 300, 400, a3}, {-100, -200, -300, -400, a3}}}

```
list1[[All, All, {1, -1}]]
```

> {{{1, a1}, {11, a1}, {22, a1}}, {{-1, a2}, {-11, a2}, {-22, a2}, {-41,
> a2}}, {{100, a3}, {-100, a3}}}

```
list1[[All, All, {2, 3}]]
```

> {{{2, 3}, {12, 13}, {23,     24}}, {{-2, -3}, {-12, -13}, {-23, -24},
> {-42, -43}}, {{200,     300}, {-200, -300}}}

As you can see, extracting elements is pretty easy. The first step is the hard part. Here is another, more idiomatic, solution to that problem:

```
MapThread[Append[#2] /@ # &, {list1, list2}]
```

It may help to think about this problem in two steps. First we need to associate each element in `list2` with each element in `list1`. Then we need to insert the associated elements from `list2` into the lists from `list1` that they are associated with. The first of these two parts can be done using `Transpose`, and then we can write a function to do the second part:

```
f[{l_, x_}] := Append[x] /@ l
f /@ Transpose[{list1, list2}]
```

This solution is not serious by any means but it represents another approach to the problem in case you're interested:

```
TakeList[
 MapThread[
  Append, {
   Flatten[list1, 1],
   Catenate@MapThread[ConstantArray, {list2, Length /@ list1}]
   }],
 Length /@ list1
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your kind explanation!! Now I can get what I want, not only for list1 and list2 but also for other lists. Though it was difficult for me to understand the last part: Catenate@MapThread[ConstantArray, {list2, Length /@ list1}], except this, I got the points. Thanks again!

Comment: @nancy yeah, it's a bit difficult to read which is one reason it shouldn't be the first way to solve the problem. It turns `{a, b, c}` into `{a, a, a, b, b, c, c, c}` where the number of each element is the number of corresponding sublists in `list1`. We then flatten `list1` so we now have one list of sublists (no nesting). Now we can easily match the elements to each other. Then we do the reverse using `TakeList`, i.e. take the flat list and make it multidimensional again. You're welcome!

Comment: I'm really greatful to you, thank you so much. Your comment enhanced my understanding. The point became clear. I think this answer will  be helpful to those who have similar question!

Answer (score 3):

```
newlist = MapThread[Thread[Join[#1, {#2}]] &, {list1, list2}]
```

> {{{1, 11, 22, a1}, {2, 12, 23, a1}, {3, 13, 24, a1}, {4, 14, 25,
> a1}}, {{-1, -11, -22, -41, a2}, {-2, -12, -23, -42,
> a2}, {-3, -13, -24, -43, a2}, {-4, -14, -25, -44,
> a2}}, {{100, -100, a3}, {200, -200, a3}, {300, -300,
> a3}, {400, -400, a3}}}

```
ext1 = MapThread[Thread[{First /@ #1, #2}] &, {list1, list2}]
```

> {{{1, a1}, {11, a1}, {22, a1}}, {{-1, a2}, {-11, a2}, {-22, a2}, {-41,
> a2}}, {{100, a3}, {-100, a3}}}

```
ext2 = Map[#[[2 ;; 3]] &, list1, {2}]
```

> {{{2, 3}, {12, 13}, {23,
> 24}}, {{-2, -3}, {-12, -13}, {-23, -24}, {-42, -43}}, {{200,
> 300}, {-200, -300}}}

Comment: Thank you for telling me how to get ext1 and ext2, directly. For ext2 script, I could also get the conbination of 1st and 4th elements:{{{1, 4}, {11, 14}, {22, 25}}, {{-1, -4}, {-11, -14}, {-22, -25}, {-41, -44}}, {{100, 
   400}, {-100, -400}}}, by ext2 = Map[{#[[1]], #[[4]]} &, list1, {2}]

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[f0]
f0 = Inner[#2 /@ # &, #, Append /@ #2, {##} &] &;;

f0[list1, list2]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3, 4, a1}, {11, 12, 13, 14, a1}, {22, 23, 24, 25, a1}},
>  {{-1, -2, -3, -4, a2}, {-11, -12, -13, -14,  a2}, {-22, -23, -24, -25, a2},
>   {-41, -42, -43, -44, a2}}, 
>  {{100, 200, 300, 400, a3}, {-100, -200, -300, -400, a3}}}
> ```

```
% == newlist
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried the script and successfully got newlist.

Answer (score 1):

```
a =
  {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {11, 12, 13, 14}, {22, 23, 24, 25}},
   {{-1, -2, -3, -4}, {-11, -12, -13, -14}, {-22, -23, -24, -25}, {-41, -42, -43, -44}}, 
   {{100, 200, 300, 400}, {-100, -200, -300, -400}}};

b = {a1, a2, a3};
```

Using `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
MapApply[Append[#1] /@ #2 &] @ Transpose[{b, a}]
```

returns

```
{{{1, 2, 3, 4, a1}, {11, 12, 13, 14, a1}, {22, 23, 24, 25, a1}}, 
 {{-1, -2, -3, -4, a2}, {-11, -12, -13, -14, a2}, {-22, -23, -24, -25, a2}, {-41, -42, -43, -44, a2}}, 
 {{100, 200, 300, 400, a3}, {-100, -200, -300, -400, a3}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {11, 12, 13, 14}, {22, 23, 24, 25}},
      {{-1, -2, -3, -4}, {-11, -12, -13, -14}, {-22, -23, -24, -25}, 
      {-41, -42, -43, -44}}, {{100, 200, 300, 400}, {-100, -200, -300, -400}}};

l2 = {a1, a2, a3};
```

---

Using `Thread` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
Thread@*Reverse /@ Thread[{l2, l1}] /. {x_?VectorQ, s_} :> Join @@ {x, {s}}

(*{{{1, 2, 3, 4, a1}, {11, 12, 13, 14, a1}, {22, 23, 24, 25, a1}},
   {{-1, -2, -3, -4, a2}, {-11, -12, -13, -14, a2}, {-22, -23, -24, -25, a2},   
   {-41, -42, -43, -44, a2}}, {{100, 200, 300, 400, a3}, {-100, -200, -300, -400, a3}}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `MapIndexed`:**

```
list1 = {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {11, 12, 13, 14}, {22, 23, 24, 
    25}}, {{-1, -2, -3, -4}, {-11, -12, -13, -14}, {-22, -23, -24, \
-25}, {-41, -42, -43, -44}}, {{100, 200, 300, 
    400}, {-100, -200, -300, -400}}}

list2 = {a1, a2, a3}

f = Map[Append[list2[[First@#2]]], #1] &;
MapIndexed[f, list1]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{{1, 2, 3, 4, a1}, {11, 12, 13, 14, a1}, {22, 23, 24, 25,     a1}},
> {{-1, -2, -3, -4, a2}, {-11, -12, -13, -14,     a2}, {-22, -23, -24,
> -25, a2}, {-41, -42, -43, -44, a2}}, {{100,     200, 300, 400, a3}, {-100, -200, -300, -400, a3}}}